# What species of short plant is this in Iran?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image][image]

Anyone knows the name of this Iranian local species?

Comment: Hi welcome to Bio.SE! Please see our [guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for writing a good species ID question. After reading the guidelines, please update your post accordingly. Otherwise, unfortunately, it'll be downvoted or closed. Thanks.

Comment: it's a chalk area species which is very generic, without a bloom photo it looks similar to 100ds of other species. You therefore need a mountain plants book specific to iran and local chalk areas.